# Can I modify a paper contract, and then mail it to the bank?

Tags: united-states, contract-law

If a bank sends me a contract to sign to apply for a credit card, can I scan the contract, modify it, and then mail it to the bank?

Comment: I suppose altering the contract and mailing it to them constitutes a valid counter offer. Of course this means the bank still decides whether it will accept the counter offer or not.

Comment: Your English is fine, by the way.

Comment: Is this a pre-approval or pre-qualification mailpiece? If it is, then your modifications mean absolutely nothing, and the box where you sign explains that very well.

Comment: Checkout the [Mirror Image Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_image_rule) @Sreehari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bank has made you an offer to contract with you: you can accept that offer by signing it and sending it back **unamended.**

You can make the bank a counter-offer by amending the document, signing it and sending it to them for their consideration and acceptance or rejection. With a bank, I would count on rejection.

Basically, if you don't like the terms, find another bank or do without the card.

Comment: What happens if the bank fails to reject (e.g. the person opening the envelope doesn't bother to pay attention to the amendment, and the card is automatically issued)?

Comment: @user6726 then the bank has accepted your offer by conduct.

Comment: This may or may not be correct. You'd need to check your state's UCC law, too, to make sure credit card contracts are indeed subject to common law vs. UCC law. Further, it is not clear that the bank has accepted your offer by conduct. This would depend in part on how big of a chance you are making to the contract is, OP. If it is a material difference (aka a big chance), then there may be an argument that the contract should be void, should the bank later notice and attempt to invalidate it.

Comment: @A.fm you seem to have typed "chance" when you meant "change".

Comment: @A.fm.: In most cases where the the bank would end up arguing that it should be void much later, void would most likely result in the result I want. (Because I would be mostly deleting objectionable terms.)